# Multiple exchanges in one channel or multiple channels with one exchange

Tags: rabbitmq, message-queue, amqp

I have a scenario where there are multiple sources sent messages to different queues and every source can send to multiple queues. I also have consumer prefetch equal to 1 for every consumer.
which is better to create one channel with multiple exchanges for every source and each exchange has its own queues or creates different channels for every source and every channel has one exchange?

Comment: A "channel" is basically a socket connection to Rabbit. You usually only have one channel open for each process rather than having to maintain several connections for the same producer (or consumer). The protocol is able to multiplex on one channel.